# SSL handshake fails after successfully exchanging both client and server certificates

Tags: ssl, apache-axis, sslhandshakeexception

My Java (1.7) client seems to be failing at the very end of the handshake process with the below exception.

I guess there is some issue with the client set up.  How should I go about debugging this?

```
...

main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 29, 85, 244, 219, 41, 146, 203, 174, 235, 86, 47, 92 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40
main, READ: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
main, RECV TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, handshake_failure
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, called closeSocket()
main, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
Exception in thread "main" AxisFault
 faultCode: {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Server.userException
 faultSubcode: 
 faultString: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
 faultActor: 
 faultNode: 
 faultDetail:
```

Comment: You seem to be starting a second handshake here.

Comment: It might be that the server is expecting a client certificate and the client does not send any or the wrong one.